# How to download an entire folder using Subversion (or another method)?

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I'm trying to download all the files and folder inside this URL: http://svn.jobeet.org/doctrine/tags/release_day_10/ at once, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

(I installed Subversion but no idea ho to use it).

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should "checkout" the source:

```
svn checkout http://svn.jobeet.org/doctrine/tags/release_day_10/
```

You can find more info about subversion on the internet, e.g.:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html

Answer (score 2):

On the command prompt type:

```
svn co http://svn.jobeet.org/doctrine/tags/release_day_10/
```

This will checkout the source tree to a folder `release_day_10` in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might be a bit obvious, but took me a few attempts to crack .... make sure you capitalise the path EXACTLY as shown in the browser link to the SVN!